# When reading CSV with `pd.read_csv`, the decimal places change (Pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

```
excel = pd.read_csv("EH_damages.csv")
```

Hello! 
I used the above code to read a csv file into python. However `0.289798953` in original excel changed to `0.289799`. Even when I saved the number to text mode in the excel, python still read it as float and the number has fewer digits like `0.289799`.

What is wrong with my code? THANKS!!

Answer (score 4):

Not all decimals can be exactly represented by floats, but that doesn't seem to
be the main issue here. What you are seeing is merely the way Pandas formats
DataFrames by default when printed.  The actual float stored in the DataFrame
may have more digits.

For example, with this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[0.289798953]})
```

You see this:

```
print(df)
#         foo
# 0  0.289799
```

But the actual float value is still `0.289798953`:

```
print(df.ix[0, 'foo'])
# 0.289798953
```

You can tell Pandas to display 9 digits after the decimal point by setting:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.9f}'.format
```

or, as [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473061/when-reading-csv-with-pd-read-csv-the-decimal-places-change-pandas/45473142?noredirect=1#comment77907218_45473142), `pd.set_option('precision', 9)`.
Then printing the DataFrame shows:

```
print(df)
#           foo
# 0 0.289798953
```

You can read more about the available [options here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_option.html).

Comment: Probably easier: `pd.set_option('precision', 9)` (or any other number)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Thanks for the improvement; I didn't know about that.

Comment: Yup. Came across the dupe that linked to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html?highlight=precision#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment) when looking for an answer to this.